# how to search the database for the keys that are themselves substrings of the search string in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Have the following data：

```
>db.abc.insert([{_id:"r"},{_id:"ro"},{_id:"roo"},{_id:"root"},{_id:"rob"}]);
```

Already know the keyword "root", need to find "_id" content "r, ro, roo, root" record，I've tried：

```
>db.abc.find({_id:{$lte:"root"}});  
{ "_id" : "r" }  
{ "_id" : "ro" }  
{ "_id" : "rob" }  
{ "_id" : "roo" }  
{ "_id" : "root" }
```

I do not need to "rob"，An equivalent pl/sql statement:

```
'root' like _id||'%'
```

Keywords may be very long.What is a good way, it is best to use an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `root` as input, then you will need to create a search query containing all the possibilities yourself, by using `$in`:

```
db.collection.find( { _id: { $in: [ 'r', 'ro', 'roo', 'root' ] } } );
```

There is currently no functionality available that searches only a *part* of a static values.

The other way around is possible - if you have "ro" then you can easily find all the `_id` values that start with "ro" by using a regular expression like:

```
db.collection.find( { _id: /^ro/ } );
```

Another alternative might by using the `text` full text search index. This will allow you to match against the *root* of words. A search for `root` will then also find `roots`. *Text search* is described at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/text-search/

Comment: I was actually a tree structure, each node has a keyword. Find all child nodes with a prefix matching, then, to find all of the parent node, encountered this problem. Keywords are not necessarily a character for each level increase, so construct all possible values​​, it will produce a lot of inactive keyword. I tried to use $where:`return substring('root',1,this._id.length)==this._id`,but return [ReferenceError: substring is not defined]

Comment: Of course none of these solutions are "ideal" and this could be a good feature to add to MongoDB, definitely worth a JIRA I think

Comment: @llx That will be a terrible query but the substring for javascript is `'root'.substring(1,this._id.length)`

Comment: As an added note, the second version doesnt solve the problem, if you look carefully he has "rob" but he doesn't want it, the regex would pick up "rob"

Comment: Assuming key length is 1000, then use IN query, using Gauss algorithm, using a 488K byte string array. With $where is the full table scan. Both comparisons, using the IN better.

Comment: I know the regexp finds rob, there are two alternatives. A question that doesn't explain what it is actually trying to do is difficult to answer... I can't read peoples minds :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in your search string if it can help: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/regex/

Comment: Would you by any chance have a regex for it?